# Can be upcast and downcast both done using dynamic_cast in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, virtual, dynamic-cast

I was going through `dynamic_cast` concept in c++.

Say suppose we have a `class Base` and 2 derived classes `class D1` and `class D2` which are derived from `Base`. Class `Base` has a virtual function `fun()`.

My questions are:

1. Can upcast and downcast both be done with `dynamic_cast`?
2. If yes, which one is more preferred and advantageous? In which cases we can go for downcast/upcast in this regard?
3. Is any of the cast not recommended or harmful?

Please explain with the use cases for the same considering the above scenarios to get a more clear picture on this. Any clear explanation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Is upcast and downcast can both be done in dynamic_cast?

Upcasting with `dynamic_cast` makes no sense whatsoever. Upcasts will always succeed. `dynamic_cast` is used when you’re not certain whether a downcast will succeed, and you thus check the result of the cast for success.

Let’s say you have a function `f` which takes a `B&` and has to decide what kind of object it gets:

```
void f(B& b) {
    D1* d1 = dynamic_cast<D1*>(&b); // notice the address-of operator!
    if (d1 != nullptr)
        std::cout << "We got a D1!\n";
    else if (dynamic_cast<D2*>(&b) != nullptr) // No need to assign to a variable.
        std::cout << "We got a D2!\n";

    // Or, with a reference:
    try {
        D1& d1_ref = dynamic_cast<D1&>(b); // reference!
        std::cout << "We got a D1!\n";
    catch (std::bad_cast const&) {
        std::cout << "It was NOT a D1 after all\n";
    }
}
```

Importantly, all the above code operates on either pointers or references. This is what we need to do in C++ to deal with polymorphic objects. We cannot just use values here.

> 2. If yes., Which one is more preferred and advantageous.? In which cases we can go for downcast/upcast in this regard?

In your case, we’d have:

```
D1 derived;
B& b = derived; // implicit upcast
b.fun();

static_cast<B&>(derived).fun(); // explicit upcast

// But actually, no upcast is of course needed to call `fun`:
derived.fun();
```

Upcast is implicit, you don’t need to use any cast for this. If you explicitly want to treat an object as a base class type, use a `static_cast`.

> 3. Is any of the cast is not recommended or harmful?

See above. For further information, read the [cppreference entry on `dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: Thanks. Now its pretty clear. But given the scenario how can we achieve simiple downcasting? If we explicitly want to treat an object as a base class type, how can we do it using static_cast.!

Comment: @ShivarajBhat: That is very useful, for instance, in the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), where a derived class inherits from a class template to which the derived class is passed as a template parameter, and the base class calls non-virtual methods of the derived class by `static_cast`-ing its `this` to the derived class using the template parameter derived class type. This is one of the pillars that ATL and WTL relied on.

Comment: @JohannGerell: Thanks Johann., That information is really helpful.

Comment: Using any cast other than an implicit or dynamic cast for upcasting can be harmful if your class hierarchy changes in the future. Suppose class `B` inherits from `A`, and you perform a static cast from `B` to `A`. In the future, you flip the hierarchy so that `A` inherits from `B` instead. The static cast will still succeed and potentially cause undefined behavior because it's now a downcast, whereas an implicit cast or a dynamic cast would be safe.

Comment: @markasoftware Class hierarchy changes are API and ABI breaking changes *anyway*. It’s not a safe change, regardless of the presence of `static_cast`s: this isn’t the only scenario in which such a change would lead to silent behavioural changes …